# How to add translatable static text in a jasperreports table

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a jasper template (jrxml), I want to create a table with the data from the following subdataset:

```
<subDataset name="mutations_detail" uuid="e09046ea-4e8d-40f9-9fad-663da9997adb">
        <field name="diseaseName" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="omim" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="carrierReproductiveRisk" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="nonCarrierReproductiveRisk" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="geneName" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="urCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="nonStudiedReproductiveRisk" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="individualName" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="diseaseDescription" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="category" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="textoTraducible" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="mutationDetails" class="java.util.List"/>
```

When I want to add translatable text to the template, I declare it as a parameter (textoTraducible) and then when generating the pdf from java it takes the value of the corresponding properties. In the case of the table I can't do it this way... if I try to access the parameter from inside the table it gives an error, it says it can't find the parameter textoTraducible, I have investigated and this error is because there is no parameter textoTraducible declared inside the subdataset, but if I declare it inside, it's painted as null because it's trying to find textoTraducible in mutationDetails, and it's not there because this is another data source. How could I solve it?

```
<componentElement>
<reportElement x="60" y="30" width="455" height="100" uuid="f34ed49b-2919-4dbf-bf3e-7937725043d0">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
</reportElement>
<jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
    <datasetRun subDataset="mutations_detail" uuid="7b565fbd-24b8-4a96-8be8-8ad422c57821">
        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{mutationDetails})]]></dataSourceExpression>
    </datasetRun>
    <jr:column width="455" uuid="10bd4945-6ad4-4b23-8606-cbafc5f489e3">
        <jr:detailCell height="100">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
            <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="455" height="30" forecolor="#003765" uuid="e88a045d-dd7e-4e8f-b982-20faa587e115"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="html">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $F{diseaseName} + "\n" + " OMIM: #" + $F{omim}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                <reportElement style="BackgroundColorStyle" x="0" y="60" width="455" height="30" forecolor="#003765" uuid="e88a045d-dd7e-4e8f-b982-20faa587e115"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="html">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{textoTraducible}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </jr:detailCell>
    </jr:column>
</jr:table>
</componentElement>
```

I've tried doing it by field, parameter and variable, but the only possible way I can see is for the text to be in mutationDetails.
That can't be since mutationDetails is taken from database, it's a different source.
I want textoTraducible to be something like this: "The disease is + $F{diseaseName} ", but since the language is also in Spanish, the text has to change, so I need it in an external file that varies depending on the language.
I hope I have explained myself, any help is good.
thank you.